# Validate a HTML Contact Form

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation, contact-form

I have a HTML Contact Form which I need validating in a certain way.

Instead of alerting the user in JavaScript if any fields have not been filled I prefer to show the words 'Field Required' below the fields which were left empty.

Here is my contact form `contact.html`:

```
<form id = "myForm" action="contact.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />


<label for="name">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1" />


<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

Here is my PHP form `contact.php` (Everything omitted apart from validation):

```
//Validation... I am building up an error message string to alert the user at the end (omitted) 

$errormessage = '';

if(!isset($_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 1){
$errormessage .= 'You have not entered your Name\n';
}

if(!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen($_POST['email']) < 1){
$errormessage .= 'You have not entered your Email Address\n';
}

if($errormessage != ''){ ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('<?php echo "$errormessage" ?>');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>

<?php } 


else {

$mail_to = 'info@email.co.uk';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

}
```

As you can see my current validation builds up a string in PHP which is going to be alerted to the user at the end (omitted) however I want to replace this method by showing the string 'Field Required' below the HTML fields which have been left empty.

Comment: Could you not move the if statements to below each input and echo in a p tag?

Comment: what `javascript` code have you tried? your current script is html and php. WIth your current code the user has to submit the form first to be prompted with the empty fields, if you want a method that checks for empty fields before form submit you will need javascript (or jquery)

Comment: use jQuery form validation - http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: @joespina I want the user to submit the form to be prompted with the empty fields, not before submit

Comment: @Fred Yes could do that but then that clashes with the `action = "contact.php"` as that is where it sends the actual form depending on if everything is valid

Comment: @RymanHolmes `contact.html` and `contact.php` are 2 different scripts. You can't display anything on `contact.html` while you are on `contact.php`. No dynamic data can be place on `contact.html` unless both are the same file and your using modrewrite to change the extensions then thats another story.

Comment: @joespina So how would I display the error messages on `contact.html` and at the same time use `contact.php` for sending the actual email

Comment: Well theres a lot of ways you can achieve your goal. 1 of them would be to use `$_GET` variables. Change `contact.html` to something like `contactform.php` it could be anything as long as its a PHP file so that you can pass variables from 1 place to the other. Same feature with what your using right now `$_POST`. Difference is that `$_GET` variables are passed via URL. You can pass the error messages there. Heres a link about `$_GET` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @joespina How would I submit the contact form if I have it as one page `contactform.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option if you are okay using some html5 features is to set the required attribute on the inputs.

> #### required
>
> This attribute specifies that the user must fill in a value before submitting a form. It  cannot be used when the type attribute is hidden, image, or a button type (submit, reset, or  button). The :optional and :required CSS pseudo-classes will be applied to the field as appropriate.

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

So your html would become:

```
<form id = "myForm" action="contact.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" required />


<label for="name">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1" required />


<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: It does rely on the browser implementing the functionality so it will have mixed results. So much like any client side validation it's no excuse to not validate on the server side as well.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer your question without deviating from your approach.

If contact.html can be parsed by php, or it were simply changed to contactform.php, you could send a query string to it indicating which fields had errors and display a message below them.

**contactform.php**

```
<form id = "myForm" action="contact.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
<?php if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == 1) { 
    echo '<br/>This field is required.'; 
} ?>


<label for="name">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1" />
<?php if (isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] == 1) { 
    echo '<br/>This field is required.'; 
} ?>
```

**contact.php**

```
$error = FALSE;

$errors = array();

if(!isset($_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 1){
    $error = TRUE;
    $errors[] = 'name=1';
}

if(!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen($_POST['email']) < 1){
    $error = TRUE;
    $errors[] = 'email=1';
}

$geterrors = (count($errors) > 1 ? implode('&',$errors) : $errors[0]);

if($error){ ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'contactform.php?<?php echo $geterrors; ?>';
</script>

...
```